# How to log something

Tags: python, function, logging

I am trying to log my code into a textfile. What I tried:

```
def do_something():
    print "test"

f = open('logtest','w')
f.write(do_something())
f.close()
```

So I want to save e.g. the "test" so that you can open the text file and read only "test". How do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

A better way of implementing this is with the logging module in Python. [link](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/logging.html)

```
import logging
LOG_FILENAME = 'example.log'
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,level=logging.INFO)

logging.info('This message should go to the log file')
```

In your particular case you can do:

```
import logging

def do_something():
    logging.info("test")

LOG_FILENAME = 'logtest'
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,level=logging.INFO)
do_something()
```

Answer (score 3):

You are currently printing in your `do_something` function. You should use the `return` statement to make the result accessible to the `write` method:

```
def do_something():
    return "test"

f = open('logtest','w')
f.write(do_something())
f.close()
```

Instead of using a combination of `open` and `close`, the better way would be to use the context manager implemented in `open`, the file will automatically be closed at the end of the `with` block:

```
with open('logtest','w') as f:
    f.write(do_something())
```

You can still `print` inside your function if you really want to:

```
def do_something():
    string = "test"

    print(string)

    return string
```

Answer (score 2):

write `return "test"` instead of `print "test"`.
the `print` function just outputs the text, while you want it returned and written to the file.